# Invoking Controller Action From JavaScript .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

A user can log into my app through Facebook. After the user presses the button to do initiate that, and authenticates through Facebook successfully, I then want the page that initiated the login, and which received the successful login information from Facebook, to essentially re-direct, to another view.  Where the user can then complete the registration process for my application. I have taken the time to read through other solutions, and I understand I may well have to use .AJAX.  Which is fine. The problem is it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<script>
  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  console.log('statusChangeCallback');
  console.log(response);

// The response object returns with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // User is logged into your app and Facebook.
    console.log("You are connected.");
    completeLogin();
    console.log("completeLogin called")
  testAPI();
} else {
  // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
}
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  function completeLogin() {
      $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '@Url.Action("List", "PotentialClient")'
      }).done(function () {
          console.log('Called ExternalLoginConfirmation');
      });
   }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
      appId: '1614609378567893',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                    // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
    });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
   // FB.getLoginStatus() gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback provided:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
   //    your app or not.
  //
  // handles these three cases in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Running a simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
    </script>
```

Where "List", in my Ajax function, is my specific controller action, and "PotentialClient" the controller class.

After I run this code, after I press the "Login via Facebook" button, in the developer console, I don't see any error about the url path.

But the page does not redirect to the view I need.

What am I most certainly overlooking or not doing yet?

Thank you, 
CM

Comment: What do your mean _But the page does not redirect to the view I need._? Where are you wanting to redirect to? No where in your code are you making a redirect (just making an ajax call, and ajax calls never redirect)

Comment: How do I do that then.

Comment: If your wanting to redirect to the `List()` method of `PotentialClientController`, thenit would be `function completeLogin() { location.href = '@Url.Action("List", "PotentialClient")'; }`

Comment: Thank you.  This does exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm close actually.  Now the app is stuck in an endless loop reloading the page I re-directed the app to.

Comment: What is the code in your `List()` method?